# Why does "return (str);" deduce a different type than "return str;" in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype, return-type-deduction

**Case 1:**

```
#include <iostream>

decltype(auto) fun()
{
        std::string str = "In fun";
        return str;
}

int main()
{
        std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
}
```

Here, program work fine in Gcc Compiler. `decltype(auto)` is deduced to be the type of `str`.

**Case 2:**

```
#include <iostream>

decltype(auto) fun()
{
        std::string str = "In fun";
        return (str); // Why not working??
}

int main()
{
        std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
}
```

Here, generated following error and **Segmentation fault**:

```
In function 'decltype(auto) fun()':
prog.cc:5:21: warning: reference to local variable 'str' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
         std::string str = "In fun";
                     ^~~
Segmentation fault
```

Why does `return (str);` giving segmentation fault?

Comment: The warning message should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I think you search for something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762662/are-parentheses-around-the-result-significant-in-a-return-statement

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That explains why the segfault - but why does `return str;` deduce `std::string`, but `return (str);` deduce `std::string&`? That's the interesting question.

Comment: @Picnix_ Thank you.  Top voted answer to that answers my question very nicely.

Comment: @Picnix_ Yes, thank you.  Another piece of C++ weirdness we all have to live with but at least the compiler caught this particular example.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Please reopen this question. It is no duplicate, because it is much more specific and useful by focusing on `c++`. The very old linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762662/are-parentheses-around-the-result-significant-in-a-return-statement is about `c` and `c++` at the same time and not so useful.

Comment: @JonasStein The accepted answer in that question explains exactly what is going on here.  The wording of the duplicate question is a little more generic, but if people are going to give a better answer to this question, they can give a better answer to the duplicate.  I would still vtc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) works in two different ways; when using with unparenthesized id-expression, it yields the exact type how it's declared (in case 1 it's `std::string`). Otherwise,

> If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
>
> a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields
> T&&;
>
> b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype yields
> T&;
>
> c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then decltype
> yields T.

and

> Note that if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is treated as an ordinary lvalue expression, thus `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` are often different types.

`(str)` is a parenthesized expression, and it's an lvalue; then it yields the type of `string&`. So you're returning a reference to local variable, it's always dangling. Dereference on it leads to UB.

Comment: Note that this is also a result of using `decltype(auto)`. If you had used plain `auto` as return type of the function, this would not have been a problem.