# decltype(auto) type deduction: return x vs. return (x)

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype, decltype-auto

I'm looking at the [isocpp.org FAQ on C++14 language extensions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language%5C), reading about [`decltype(auto)`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#decltype-auto):

> ...
>
> **Note:** `decltype(auto)` is primarily useful for deducing the return type of forwarding functions and similar wrappers, as shown above, where you want the type to exactly “track” some expression you’re invoking. However, decltype(auto) is not intended to be a widely used feature beyond that. In particular, although it can be used to declare local variables, doing that is probably just an antipattern since a local variable’s reference-ness should not depend on the initialization expression. Also, it is sensitive to how you write the return statement. These two functions have different return types:
>
> ```
> decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_1() { auto str = lookup1(); return str;  }
> decltype(auto) look_up_a_string_2() { auto str = lookup1(); return(str); }
> ```
>
> The first returns string, the second returns `string &`, which is a reference to the local variable `str`.

My question: Shouldn't the return types in the example be the other way around, I mean, the parentheses should form an expression whose type should be either a non-reference (or an rvalue-reference?); and without the parentheses, saying `str` means "lvalue reference to `str`". Am I wrong?

Comment: What should be the other way around? The advice or the return types?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615981/9593596) seems relevant.

Comment: @StoryTeller: See edit.

Comment: In short: the return types are respectively `decltype(str)` and `decltype((str))`. The first one triggers the special case where `decltype`'s operand is the naked name of a variable, and the rules are different (it mimicks the variable's type exactly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The FAQ is correct, intuition notwithstanding

<sub>(@lubgr pointed out a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615981/9593596) to another question)</sub>

The language specification says:

> If the argument is either the unparenthesised name of an object/function ... then the decltype specifies the declared type of the entity specified by this expression.
>
> If the argument is any other expression of type T, then ...
>   b) if the value category of expression is lvalue, then the decltype specifies T&
>   ...
>   Note that if the name of an object is parenthesised, it becomes an lvalue expression, thus decltype(arg) and decltype((arg)) are often different types.

So, the non-parenthesized case is an exceptional/special case, apparently introduced  to facilitate returning references with decltype(auto); without the special-casing, the rule @StoryTeller quotes is in effect:

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

and this would have make it difficult to return references.

Definitely ranks up there with other magick definitions such as the destruction order of tuples or empty strings having 0 at index 0, temporary lifetime extension with references and other similar wonders...

Comment: There is really nothing odd or new here if you ask me. The exception for unparenthesized *id-expressions* has been there since the `decltype` specifier was originally introduced in C++11 [\[dcl.type.simple\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.type.simple#4)…`decltype(auto)` simply follows the existing decltype rules for type deduction, which is the whole point…

Answer (score 7):

Yes the parentheses form an expression. Expressions are not of reference type, [ever](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#5).

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

"reference to T" means both lvalue and rvalue reference. But the expression does have a value category. `str` as an expression is an lvalue, and so is `(str)` since parentheses preserve type and value category.

Since the `decltype` is applied to a lvalue expression in the second case, it produces a lvalue reference.

In the first case, the special pleading rule for id-expressions returns the "type of the entity", which is a value type.

Comment: Are you sure about your first sentence as stated? If that were the case, how would we ever be able to use reference types as function arguments?

Comment: @einpoklum -  Very sure. If `a` is a reference to something, then `a` is an lvalue expression designating that something. A reference parameter can therefore bind to the thing being designated. There's appropriate wording in how references are initialized from other expressions.

Comment: Please add the breaking change of [P2266](https://wg21.link/P2266R3) c++23 move-eligible context. I wonder why [\[dcl.type.decltype\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1) is prioritized to the added [\[expr.prim.id.unqual\]#4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#4) by P2266. Please clearify this.

Comment: @sandthorn - This is a 3 year old post about C++14 *specifically*. I suggest you post a new C++23 focused question if you want an answer to why the proposal does what it does.