# What's the purpose of redundant parentheses in return(NULL)

Tags: c

I saw the following code snippet in some C program:

```
char *x;

if (s == NULL)
    return(NULL);
if ((x = strdup(s)))
    return x;
```

What's the purpose of redundant parentheses in return(NULL)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parenthesis surrounding return values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161879/parenthesis-surrounding-return-values)

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the `if` statement below, the author simply likes writing parentheses.

Theoretically, since `NULL` is a preprocessor macro you could define it to something that is *not* enclosed in parens, and therefore might have different behavior depending on which expression it is part of due to operator precedence rules -- in which case, wrapping it in extra parens would be "safer".

Practically, this isn't going to happen. Even contemplating such a scenario makes me feel dirty, so I cannot imagine what would be the fate of someone who actually did this.

Comment: In the `if` statement, parentheses are usually a good practice when assigning a value, as in the example.

Comment: @Macmade: Sure, but... there's nothing else in there apart from the assignment! I did write parens around assignments myself back when I still thought that being terse was good, but not when there's nothing else to mix in the expression.

Comment: The parenthesis in the `if` prevent some compilers from issuing a warning about using an assignment in an if.

Comment: The redundant parentheses in the if statement will suppress a warning from gcc about using '=' instead of '=='.

Comment: @StephenCanon: In which case you should take the message and stop using assignments in conditionals. This is not 1980. :-)

Comment: @Jon: "People who don't know the language find it confusing" is not a good reason for avoiding use of a language feature.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Sorry, but who said anything about people finding it confusing? The point is readability and maintainability. Moreover, "the compiler allows it" is a really bad reason for *making* use of a language feature.

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons:

1. Some people really like extraneous parentheses.  I don't, but this harms no one.
2. Some people like to be able to define `return` as macro when they are debugging such that it does some form of additional logging before returning normally.  These people are nuts.

Comment: +1 for the second item, and especially for the last sentence.

Comment: +1 anyway, but actually, the "harms no one" thing is not quite true. Some readers (myself included) have a really hard time following and matching excessive nested parentheses, and greatly appreciate efforts to avoid increasing the nesting with redundant ones...

Answer (score 2):

Some people like parens on their returns.  My only quibble is that the code is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Some people view `return` as a function so they put the extra parentheses. Even if `return` is actually a statement.

Note that some other people also view `sizeof` as a standard library function and like to put extra parentheses when the operand is an expression. Of course `sizeof` is an operator and not a function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific purpose for them in this case.  Usually I prefer putting parenthesis for return statements.
You should either consistently put them or not put them at all.
One possible explanation for the inconsistency here is that NULL is a macro, and some people have a habit of surrounding macros with parenthesis to make sure they are properly contained.