# Difference between return() and simple return

Tags: java

I am just coding and a simple idea (*obviously question*) comes to my mind that if I have a function like :

```
int fun1(int p){
  return(p); 
}
```

and I have a function like this:

```
int fun1(int p){
  return p; ==> absence of parenthesis
}
```

so what the difference between those 2?

Comment: There's no difference at all, it's just an old convention.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161879/parenthesis-surrounding-return-values

Comment: First one with `()` just adds clutter. Majority of Java is coded without unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference. You can decide to use parens if it makes things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a coding convention otherwise **NO** any differences

Answer (score 2):

There is zero difference. It's just a redundant way of writing the return-expression.

It dates from some very bad old days of C programming when some people wanted to make return statements look like function calls, or if/while statements.

The fallacy in that was that they *aren't* function calls or if/while statements.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no difference between these two its upto you to decide which one you want to use.