# Why does my professor use return(0);?

Tags: c, coding-style

In all of my C labs, my professor, without fail, uses `return(0);` instead of (and correct me if I'm wrong) the preferred `return 0;`. Shouldn't a C professor know good programming style?

I wonder this because my C textbook (Problem Solving and Program Design in C) also uses this format. It also puts a newline between `int` and `main()`, which I find a bit odd.

Could it simply be that older versions of C used this format and she (as well as the book) never adapted? Or is this just downright bad programming style? Or am I completely off base here?

Comment: It's just a different style.  You'll notice that older professors will tend to do that sort of thing.

Comment: It's a less-trendy style. Some old projects still use them.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/161879/10396

Comment: Have you asked your professor?

Comment: Having a pair of parentheses does not make a difference (to a compiler, anyway). As my professor used to say when students complained to him about something making no difference, "if it does not make any difference to you, then why not make it the way that I ask you?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely a style choice, and user preference.  There isn't a real reason to prefer one style over the other.

Granted, I prefer `return 0;` and not using extra newlines, but there is no technical advantage or disadvantage to either style.  I would hesitate to call one style "good" and the other "bad".