# Why is this function returning the ASCII value if there is no match in switch cases?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
int foo(char c)
{
  switch(c)
  {
    case '1':
     return(1);
    case '2':
    return(2);
  } 
}

int main()
{
cout << foo('a');
}
```

This program prints 97 .

** It prints the ASCII value as output if none of switch case matches.
Why is the function returning the ASCII value if none of the cases match**

Comment: Undefined beahviour. You have to return allways a value;

Comment: And what do you return from `foo` if none of the cases in the `switch` is matched? Not returning anything from a function declared to do that leads to *undefined behavior*, which makes the whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: Don;t make `return` look like a function.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. *warning C4715: 'foo': not all control paths return a value*

Comment: @SouravGhosh why? it's a one of the conventions (one I don't like, but still)

Comment: @CIsForCookies Well, just because we can write `[5]array` and it's valid every bit, we don't use that, right? Similar here. Also, can you cite the source of the convention you mentioned, I'd like to see that.

Comment: @SouravGhosh [5]array is confusing. return (1) is very simple to understand... I hope you don't think that using parentheses when not necessary is bad (for example: _sizeof 1.1_ vs. _sizeof(1.1)_ )

Comment: @CIsForCookies Still, I'd stick to my statement. YMMV. :)

Comment: @CIsForCookies AFAIK there is a problem optimizing the return. But I don't remeber what exactly it was. Maybe RVO or something like that.

Comment: @CIsForCookies [a good read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/161879/2173917).

Comment: @manni66 I looked around and found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238786/does-c-compiler-remove-optimize-useless-parentheses)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I also saw that :). I guess there's no accounting for taste, so both are fine

Answer (score 2):

Your program behaviour is *undefined*: you must have an explicit return value on any function returning an `int` (other than `main`).

(What you appear to be observing is a corruption of the stack; 97 is the ASCII value for the lower case letter `a` that you've passed as the function parameter).

Comment: Iam running in DEV c++ ,it runs without any error and prints the output

Comment: @Kishore: Absolutely: that's an acceptable manifestation of *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Now i got that output is due to corruption of stack.But should it not return an error as "reached the end of a non void function"

Comment: @Kishore the *compiler* tells you that. C itself has no inherent error checking.

Comment: @WeatherVane Now I have enabled  the compiler  warning . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case '1':
          return(1);
        case '2':
          return(2);

        //code to execute if 'c' does not equal the value following any of the cases
        default:
          return(-1);
    } 
}

int main() {
    cout << foo('a');
}
```

OR

```
// simple char to int without switch
int foo(char c) {

   /*
   // reject unwanted char 
   if (c=='a') {
       return -1;
   }
   */

   // convert char to int
   return (int)c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is UB. The `foo` function gets an input it doesn't handle, since none of your cases support input `'a'`. What's probably happening under the hood (if I may try to explain this UB in your specific case) is that `foo` returns the input it gets casted to `int`, meaning `cout << (int)('a');`

Your switch case should contain a `default` for such cases, for example:

```
int foo(char c)
{
  switch(c)
  {
    case '1':
      return(1);
    case '2':
      return(2);
    default:
      return (-1); // indicates error!!
  } 
}

int main()
{
int tmp = foo('a');
if (tmp != -1)
    cout << tmp;
else
    cout << "bad input";
}
```