# How to restart program without it saving its values (C)

Tags: c, function, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that can read and count how many digits a number has, this is my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int a, b=0;
   printf("Hey welcome to how many digits your number has!\n");
   xyz:
   printf("To begin enter a Number = ");
   scanf("%d",&a);

   while (a!=0) {
    a/=10;
    ++b;
   }

   printf("your number has %d digits\n",b);
   int choice;
   printf("do you want to use another number?\nIf yes enter \"1\"\nif no enter \"2\"\n");
   scanf("%d",&choice);

   if (choice==1){
    goto xyz;
   }

   else if (choice==2){
    return 0;
   }

return 0;
}
```

This works great for the first time around but when I go back up and repeat it seems that value of 'b' from previous attempt has been stored..
how can I start again without it storing the value of the variable 'b' and keep the value of b = 0?

Comment: Put `b=0` under `xyz`

Comment: Nice efforts. Try to think of a different solution without using `goto`. It is not a good practice to use `goto` in codes. Happy coding :)

Comment: There are few good uses of `goto`. This is none of them. Use a loop, spaghetti belong on a plate with a good sauce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your goto doesn't include an initialisation of `b = 0`

```
xyz:
b = 0;
```

I **strongly** suggest you forget the `goto` keyword. It easily leads to unreadable and undebuggable code. Try using a loop instead :

```
int main()
{
   int choice = 1;
   while (choice == 1)
   {
       int a, b = 0;
       printf("Hey welcome to how many digits your number has!\n");
       printf("To begin enter a Number = ");
       scanf("%d", &a);

       while (a != 0)
       {
           a /= 10;
           ++b;
       }

       printf("your number has %d digits\n",b);
       //removed declaration of choice
       printf("do you want to use another number?\nIf yes enter \"1\"\nif no enter \"2\"\n");
       scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! exactly what was looking for thanks!

Comment: `do ... while` would catch the corner case when `0` is entered.

Comment: I'd advice against `return (0);` instead of `return 0;`. It makes it look like a function call. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161879/parenthesis-surrounding-return-values

Comment: @Jabberwocky I always have been used to use parenthesis for the return value. As stated in the accepted answer of the link, *"The parenthesis became a habit and it stuck."*

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is most obviously that `b` is not re-initialized to `0` inside the part within the `xyz` label. Hence the values just keep adding up instead of starting the count for a new input. so the fix would be:

```
xyz:
b = 0;
```

But it's advised not to use `goto` as it tends to create confusing code and may lead to infinite loops. Refer to this article below:

[Why should you avoid `goto`?](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Learn/Blogs/Blog-Details/ArtMID/10198/ArticleID/15289/Why-should-GOTO-be-avoided)

Use `while` or `do-while` instead... as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int a, b=0, choice; //declared choice here
   printf("Hey welcome to how many digits your number has!\n");
   do {
   b = 0;
   printf("To begin enter a Number = ");
   scanf("%d",&a);

   while (a!=0) {
    a/=10;
    ++b;
   }
             // removed declaration of choice from here and placed it along with other declarations in main()
   printf("your number has %d digits\n",b);
   printf("do you want to use another number?\nIf yes enter \"1\"\nif no enter \"2\"\n");
   scanf("%d",&choice);
   }while(choice == 1); //repeat the process again if user inputs choice as 1, else exit

return 0;
}
```